# my Array from API response is logged perfectly but it doesn't work when i try to display a title of one object from HTML

Tags: arrays, angular, angular16

I used the heros example and do the same steps as used in the example

this is my service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, map, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';


@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class LookupServices  {
  apiUrl = 'https://localhost:1400/api/lookups'
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
  getRegions(): Observable<Lookups[]> {
    return this.http.get<Lookups[]>(`${this.apiUrl}/regions`)
  }
}

export class Lookups {
  id: number;
  title: string;
  constructor(id:number, title:string) {
    (3)
    this.id = id;
    this.title = title;
  }
}
```

then in  My Component.ts :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { LookupServices, Lookups } from '../services/lookup.services'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-main-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './main-dashboard.component.html',
})
export class MainDashbaordComponent implements OnInit {
  regions: Lookups[] = [];
  constructor(private lookupServices: LookupServices) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getRegions();

  }

  getRegions(): void {
    this.lookupServices.getRegions().subscribe((data: Lookups[]) => {
      this.regions = data;
      console.log(this.regions)
    })
    
  }
}
```

and at least i use the *ngFor loop to display the region but unfortunately it doesn't work as expected to display the title of the region

my component.html:

```
<div class="row">
  <form novalidate="" class="form">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xl-3">
        <select class="form-select form-select-solid form-select-lg fw-bold"
                name="country">
          <option value="">Select a Country...</option>
          <ng-container *ngFor="let region of regions">
            <option value="region.id">{{region?.title}}</option>
          </ng-container>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

at last when i try to know the length of the array, the returned value was undefined, so i am guessing that i didn't see it as an array as suppose.

this is how the log is displayed:

```
{content: Array(10), succeeded: true, message: null, errors: null}
content
: 
Array(10)
0
: 
{id: 1, title: 'Region 1'}
1
: 
{id: 2, title: 'Region 2'}
2
: 
{id: 3, title: 'Region 3'}
3
: 
{id: 4, title: 'Region 4'}
4
: 
{id: 5, title: 'Region 5'}
5
: 
{id: 6, title: 'Region 6'}
6
: 
{id: 7, title: 'Region 7'}
7
: 
{id: 8, title: 'Region 8'}
8
: 
{id: 9, title: 'Region 9'}
9
: 
{id: 10, title: 'Region 10'}
length
: 
10
```

Comment: It might be something else non-obvious but try putting a `*ngIf="regions"` on your ng-container. Also, are there any error messages in the browser's console?

Comment: Seems to me that you are treating the whole returned object as just a regions array, while the log you posted clearly says that the regions are only one property of the returned object. So, instead of `this.regions = data` try `this.regions = data.content`.

Comment: There is no error in the console.

Comment: `LookupServices.getRegions` is asynchronous. But the call in `onNgInit()` doesn't wait for the async to complete ... Thus, when you are rendering your component, the call hasn't completed yet and `this.regions` is still the empty array you initilaized it with ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Likely it's because you're setting `this.regions` to the whole `data` object, when it seems more like you just want the content... `this.regions = data.content`, as the `content` value is the actual array of region objects.